# Access original SIP INVITE headers from Twilio

Tags: twilio, sip

My solution to establish a sip call was developed using Twilio and SIP domain resources they provide. I use a webhook call configuration which works perfectly. But the challenge I face is that I need to retrieve the original SIP INVITE headers which Twilio uses to initiate a connection to my webhook. Based on this [doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sip-twiml) I see that some params they sent were grabbed from SIP INVITE headers.

Is it possible to get this data (SIP INVITE headers) in a webhook request (params or headers) or use Twilio API?

Actually, there is the only source I found is in SIP PCAP Log file (Call log) which does not work for me

Comment: I once asked technical support who, at the time, confirmed the SIP PCAP log is only available from within the Console website. This still seems to be the only way to get the full SIP info. What is in the SIP invite header that you are needing?

Comment: hey @jassent, thanks for your reply, yeah, probably, you are right. Well, I need all sip invite headers to use some third-party API.